# How do I find the UUID of a virtual machine?

Tags: c++, c, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am working on a licensing technique. I need it to expire after 30 days. In the mean time if user changes his/her time to the past time the licensing period is extending. I am new at this. so i thought of generating the license according to the VM's UUID. But i dont know how to retrive the UUID from server as all the info is stored in server.
My Guest OS is always windows 7. It wont change. Now I need to find the UUID of the machine in which the Windows 7 is installed.

Help me out please.

Comment: You mean `UDID`? `UUID` is entirely different thing. And what do you mean UUID of a virtual machine?

Comment: Universal Unique Identifier of the virtual machine

Comment: Note: Many VMs (such as VirtualBox) will generate a UUID for each machine created. The link to "Generating a unique machine id" does not specifically answer the question of getting a VM UUID from inside the VM, but the information there *may* provide a way to accomplish what the OP needs.